# JBOSS gives org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: auth.conf cannot be read

Tags: jboss, apache-kafka, wildfly, kafka-consumer-api, wildfly-10

When I deploy war  of my simple kafka project (which works fine as a jar ) in wildfly v 10 , i get some zookeeper connection exception[1].This occurs when kafka listener starts to connect with zookeeper

[1]]

```
15:21:58,531 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 82) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ratha.war".component.KafkaServiceBean.START: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ratha.war".component.KafkaServiceBean.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:134)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:88)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.getComponentInstance(SingletonComponent.java:124)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.start(SingletonComponent.java:138)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:54)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: File jar:file:/Users/ratha/projects/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/picketbox/main/picketbox-4.9.4.Final.jar!/auth.confcannot be read.
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:349)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: File jar:file:/Users/ratha/projects/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/picketbox/main/picketbox-4.9.4.Final.jar!/auth.confcannot be read.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasUtils.isZkSecurityEnabled(JaasUtils.java:95)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.connectZk(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:184)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:129)
    at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:66)
    at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:69)
    at kafka.consumer.Consumer$.createJavaConsumerConnector(ConsumerConnector.scala:120)
    at kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(ConsumerConnector.scala)
```

Comment: Maybe your Wildfly installation is just corrupted or you may have some permissions problem. Did you try to reinstall it, maybe on another drive/device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the following code in Kafka

```
String loginConfigFile = System.getProperty(JAVA_LOGIN_CONFIG_PARAM);
if (loginConfigFile != null && loginConfigFile.length() > 0) {
        File configFile = new File(loginConfigFile);
        if (!configFile.canRead()) {
            throw new KafkaException("File " + loginConfigFile + "cannot be read.");
        }
...
```

At Wildfly 10, the properties of JAVAX_LOGIN_CONFIG PARAM (`java.security.auth.login.config`) is set to `jar:file:/opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/picketbox/main/picketbox-4.9.4.Final.jar!/auth.conf`.

At Wildfly 9, the above property is null. Thus, the quick workaround is to mimic Wildfly 9 by setting that property to null.

To do that, modify your standalone.conf with `-Djava.security.auth.login.config=` option, ie. empty value.  My standalone.conf will look like this:

```
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
    JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
    JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.auth.login.config="
else
    echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: $JAVA_OPTS"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a property called ***zookeeper.sasl.client*** which is **true** by default and it means SASL Authentication is enabled. If we require SASL Authentication, then more configuration has to be done. If not required, then we can just simply disable SASL Authentication by setting this property to **false**.

```
System.setProperty("zookeeper.sasl.client", "false");
```

This is described at https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.2-alpha/zookeeperProgrammers.html under "Client Configuration Parameters" section.