# org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceContributor: Provider org.hibernate.spatial.integration.SpatialInitializer not a subtype

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-9

Im using following hibernate jars [1]; When I deploy my war file in wildfly 9 I get following error.

How can I overcome this issue?

```
5:34:53,204 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."test2dbwar.war#test2dbwar-persistence-unit": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."test2dbwar.war#test2dbwar-persistence-unit": java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceContributor: Provider org.hibernate.spatial.integration.SpatialInitializer not a subtype
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:665)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceContributor: Provider org.hibernate.spatial.integration.SpatialInitializer not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.applyServiceContributors(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.build(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1035)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
    ... 7 more

15:34:53,211 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 12) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "test2dbwar.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"test2dbwar.war#test2dbwar-persistence-unit\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"test2dbwar.war#test2dbwar-persistence-unit\": java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceContributor: Provider org.hibernate.spatial.integration.SpatialInitializer not a subtype
    Ca
```

[1]

- hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar
- hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.1.Final.jar
- hibernate-java8-5.1.0.Final.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
- hibernate-spatial-5.1.0.Final.jar
- hibernate-validator-5.2.1.Final.jar

**EDIT**
Jboss-deployment-structure.xml;

```
<jboss-deployment-structure >

  <deployment>

     <!-- exclude-subsystem prevents a subsystems deployment unit processors running on a deployment -->

     <!-- which gives basically the same effect as removing the subsystem, but it only affects single deployment -->

     <exclude-subsystems>

        <subsystem name="org.hibernate" />

    </exclude-subsystems>

    <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies     -->

    <exclusions>

        <module name="org.hibernate" />

    </exclusions>

  </deployment>

</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516192/java-lang-classcastexception-sun-reflect-generics-reflectiveobjects-parameteriz), you are likely to get all kind of surprising errors when you use incompatible versions. As you can see in the stack trace, you are actually using Hibernate 4 since Wildfly 9 includes Hibernate 4.

Comment: I have excluded Hibernate 4 version in jboss-deployment structure.xml (Kept in WEB_INF folder root level)and allowing to use packaged jars in my war. I don't know how it still uses jboss libraries. After the jboss-deployment-structure.xml change,I get above issue.

Comment: @Ratha: well, how does your jboss-deployment-structure.xml look like?

Comment: I edited my question with my jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Comment: @Ratha; maybe you have to exclude other stuff, like jpa as well. unfortunately, that is maybe not straightforward. if possible you could try if it works with Wildfly 10.

Comment: I was able to overcome this Hibernate issue in wildfly 10, but unfornately, i had another issue in wildfly 10 with my kafka initialisation. (Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36761018/jboss-gives-org-apache-kafka-common-kafkaexception-auth-conf-cannot-be-read) Due to that issue, I have moved to wildfly 9, where i didn't face that //auth.confcannot be read.// issue.